# Android fragment JSON <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: java, android, mysql, json, android-fragments

I am trying to establish a connection to a MYSQL database within my Android Application.

I have been following this tutorial: http://www.trustingeeks.com/connect-android-app-to-mysql-database/

Basically its populating a textview from a JSON request.

The difference is that I need to get the data connection working within a Fragment.

This is where I have an issue, nothing is happening. Below is my attempt to implement the tutorial into a fragment:

```
public class FragmentFour extends Fragment{

private String jsonResult;
private String url = "http://cpriyankara.coolpage.biz/employee_details.php";
private TextView resultView;
private static View view;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    if (view != null) {
        ViewGroup parent = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
        if (parent != null)
            parent.removeView(view);
    }
    try {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_four, container, false);


        resultView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.result);
        StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        getData();


    } catch (InflateException e) {

    }
    return view;
}


public void getData(){

    String result = "";

    InputStream isr = null;

    try{

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();

        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://ieeehiit.host22.com/myfile.php"); //YOUR PHP SCRIPT ADDRESS

        // HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://172.23.193.32/elift-test/myfile.php"); //YOUR PHP SCRIPT ADDRESS

        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        isr = entity.getContent();

    }

    catch(Exception e){

        Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection "+e.toString());

        resultView.setText("Couldnt connect to database");

    }///convert response to string

    try{

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(isr,"iso-8859-1"),8);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        String line = null;

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {

            sb.append(line + "\n");

        }

        isr.close();

        result=sb.toString();

    }

    catch(Exception e){

        Log.e("log_tag", "Error  converting result " + e.toString());

    }//parse json data

    try {

        String s = "";

        JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);

        for(int i=0; i<jArray.length();i++){

            JSONObject json = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

            s = s +"Name : "+json.getString("id")+" "+json.getString("username");  }

        resultView.setText(s);

    } catch (Exception e)
```

{ // TODO: handle exception

```
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Parsing Data "+e.toString());

    }

}
```

}

Everything executes fine but nothing is happening in the textView. I looked in the logcat and noticed:

```
"2-09 21:06:05.155  13519-13519/com.example.nottinghamtouristapp E/log_tag﹕ Error Parsing Data org.json.JSONException: Value <!DOCTYPE of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray"
```

I am very new to android development, so this issue is likely due to my lack of experience with fragments.I do apologise if I seem boneheaded and arrogant posting posting for help. I feel to have exhausted all that comes to mind!

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: The error says it all: The "json" response from the server is **NOT** json. It's HTML. A json response cannot start with `<!DOCTYPE`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok try this approach

Iniatialize the variables

```
private View rootView;
private ListView lv;
private String jsonResult;
private String url = "http://cpriyankara.coolpage.biz/employee_details.php";
ProgressDialog pDialog;
private TextView resultView;
```

Modify your AsyncTask

```
public class JsonReadTask extends AsyncTask<String , Void, String> {
        public JsonReadTask() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity(), ProgressDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK);
            pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
            pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
            pDialog.setMessage("Your message");
            pDialog.setCancelable(false);
            pDialog.setInverseBackgroundForced(true);
            pDialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0]);
            try {
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
                jsonResult = inputStreamToString(
                        response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
                customList = new ArrayList<>();

                JSONObject jsonResponse = new JSONObject(jsonResult);
                JSONArray jsonMainNode = jsonResponse.optJSONArray("array-name");
                for (int i = 0; i < jsonMainNode.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                    String name = jsonChildNode.optString("name");

                }
                return name;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                getActivity().finish();
            }
            return null;
        }

        private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
            String rLine = "";
            StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
            BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            try {
                while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
                    answer.append(rLine);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                getActivity().finish();
            }
            return answer;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(customList == null){
                Log.d("ERORR", "No result to show.");
                return;
            }
            resultView.setText(result);
            pDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }// end async task

    public void accessWebService() {
        JsonReadTask task = new JsonReadTask();
        task.execute(new String[]{url});
    }
```

Hope it helps!!!